# force http instead of https only for a particular file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For a particular file, I want to force http instead of https

Example:

```
https://example.com/test.php?parameter1=value1
```

should be send to

```
http://example.com/test.php?parameter1=value1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but try this .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^parameter1=.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^test\.php/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

This will redirect ONLY if QUERY string `parameter1=something` is present in the original URL. If you want to redirect all `/test.php` URIs to https then remove the 1st RewriteCond line.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^https://example.com(.*) http://example.com$1 [R=301,NC]
```