# Openshift: Change the https to http

Tags: openshift

I create a application on the openshift platform,

but the url to my app always use `https`

I think it slow down the visit speed

How can I change it to `http`?

Comment: Why exactly do you think it slows down the "visit speed"?

Comment: @akluth: at least in my country, my experience told me that

Comment: You can just change the URL to http when you login... If you want your USERS to always access via http see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753591/force-http-instead-of-https-only-for-a-particular-file).

Comment: @akluth He's referring to the fact that communication would have to be encrypted and decrypted by both client and server. The increase in server load is negligible (about 1% on average).. the increase in client processing although significantly higher than that of the server is also relatively low because of he incredible SSL performance browsers put out these days. If your visitors will be on WinXP machines running IE6, then and only then would I worry about the performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Google Chrome or Chromium with OpenShift?

OpenShift is currently returning some header information that is causing Chrome browsers to automatically redirect from http to https.

The bug has been documented here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=908417 (login required)

This should be fixed in the next update to OpenShift, and when using Google Chrome version 26 or later.

Comment: This bug has now been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You would enter to "Applications/Routes", then enter to your micro-service and clic in "Actions/Edit".

On botton of page, you have a check about Security. 
If you activate the check, your route is https, if you deactivate the check, your url will be http.

Regards.