# How to change OpenShift Jenkins to use HTTP instead of HTTPs

Tags: http, jenkins, https, openshift

I create an application Jenkins on Openshift, but when I tried to visit http://[app_name]-[domain_name].rhcloud.com/, it will be redirected to https://[app_name]-[domain_name].rhcloud.com/.

I curl the http address, the result is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://[app_name]-[domain_name].rhcloud.com/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at [app_name]-[domain_name].rhcloud.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

If I do not want to be redirected to https, what should I do?
I searched in my openshift folders, but cannot find any helpful things

Comment: Have you seen [Openshift: Change the https to http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442238/openshift-change-the-https-to-http) already?

Answer (score 1):

You should change it on your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^https://[app_name]-[domain_name].rhcloud.com/(.*)  http://[app_name]-[domain_name].rhcloud.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: but I am using OpenShift, so I can not find the way to update the .htaccess file.

Comment: In fact, I use 'ps aux' to view the processes, the params of jenkins' process were "--ajp13Port=-1 --controlPort=-1 --logfile=/dev/stdout --httpPort=8080 --handlerCountMax=45 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 --httpListenAddress=127.4.101.1". So maybe the 80 port of https was using port forwarding?